# After installing mediawiki plugin on Tuleap it shows 404 Not Found

Tags: mediawiki, tuleap, bugzilla

I have installed MediaWiki and Bugzilla Reference plugins on our Tuleap installation but when I click in the administration page it gives me 404 Bot Found error message. Other plugins e.g. Trackers, Agile Dashboard are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was happening because there was no `mediawiki.conf` file created `in /etc/nginx/conf.d/tuleap-plugins.`

My initial attempt was copying one of the other files like `admindelegation.conf`, and matching renames of every `admindelegation` to `mediawiki` fixed it.  That worked, except for invalid CSS, because additional rewrites were needed.

The proper fix was to copy /usr/share/tuleap/plugins/mediawiki/etc/nginx18/mediawiki.conf to /etc/nginx/conf.d/tuleap-plugins